# How can shift left << give different results in different functions?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have been debugging a problem in a C++ library, and found a strange difference between **literal 0** and a **variable set to 0** but **only inside the library**. If I copy the code out into my own code it works as expected.

The library code is shifting a `1` down a long integer to mask off one bit at a time. When sending a certain code (REPEAT key) you send a kind of dummy data packet, and "no bits" so it transmits the headers and no data. I was assuming the for-loop would skip the loop if there were no bits to send.

I have simplified it down to break apart the assignment, and added the following debugging. I'm just repeating the steps for both `nbits` and the literal `0` I added.

```
void  IRsend::sendNEC (unsigned long data,  int nbits){

    Serial.println(data, HEX);
    Serial.print(" nbits = ");
    Serial.println( nbits);
    if(nbits == 0) Serial.println("nbits == 0"); else Serial.println("nbits != 0 "); 
    Serial.print(" 0 - 1 = ");
    Serial.println(0 - 1);
    Serial.print(" nbits - 1 = ");
    Serial.println(nbits - 1);
    Serial.print(" (1UL << (0 - 1) = ");
    Serial.println(1UL << (0 - 1));
    Serial.print(" (1UL << (nbits - 1) = ");
    Serial.println(1UL << (nbits - 1));
    ...

    // the part I was originally debugging:
        for (unsigned long  mask = 1UL << (nbits - 1);  mask;  mask >>= 1) {
    ...
}

called like:

  irsend.sendNEC(0xFFFFFFFF, 0);
```

This surprisingly gives the following output:

```
FFFFFFFF
 nbits = 0
 nbits == 0
 0 - 1 = -1
 nbits - 1 = -1
 (1UL << (0 - 1) = 0
 (1UL << (nbits - 1) = 1
```

How can the last two results be different? `nbit` is 0, so why does literal 0 shift differently when they both end up as -1 (I added the extra parentheses to be sure)?

And why, when I copy the exact same debug code into my code which calls that library, and call a test function like:

```
void runtest(unsigned long data,  int nbits){
/// same debug ... 
}
void setup() {
  runtest(0xFFFFFFFF, 0);
}
```

I get the expected output:

```
-- Same test again --
FFFFFFFF
 nbits = 0
nbits == 0
 0 - 1 = -1
 nbits - 1 = -1
 (1UL << (0 - 1) = 0
 (1UL << (nbits - 1) = 0
```

I can only guess that 0 == 0 exactly, e.g. if its defaulting to a longer type 0?

This is using the Arduino IRRemote library: https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/ir_NEC.cpp

Its running on an ATmega328, I'm building on MacOSX presumably with avr-gcc in the Arduino 1.8.10 IDE.

Comment: Is shifting by a negative offset even defined behavior?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError very good point! I didn't think that far ahead... I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a draft C++ standard [expr.shift](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift):

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative**, or greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand.

Your code has undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

From [this shift reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators)

> ... if the value of the right operand **is negative** or is greater or equal to the number of bits in the promoted left operand, **the behavior is undefined**

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

You're not allowed to have negative shifts, it's undefined behavior.